# How can I resize a image located at /sdcard/image.png using ADB command/shell?

Tags: android, image, resize, adb

I'm manipulating the Android device in an ADB session, fetching back the screenshots captured by command `screencap -p /sdcard/image.png`.

Due to the very limited network bandwidth, I want to resize the captured png file to a smaller one, before sending it back through the network.

How to do such a resizing using ADB command? I already found some additionally installed apps could do this for me, but that requires a manual operation to open that app, and resizing the image through its GUI functionality. But how to do it pragmatically? in a ADB command manner?

Comment: So you are using wireless adb? because by default adb uses USB and thus no network is involved. I am not aware of a command-line tool available on Android that is able to resize images. You will have to upload/push your own tool for resizing the image before pulling it.

Comment: @Robert that's a bit longer story to tell...In fact, I'm using that ADB connection through a custom reverse proxy to connect to some virtual android devices deployed in a remote datacenter, so the bandwidth outbound of that datacenter matters. Thanks for your reply. and one more question: what kind of tool may I push to the device to do the resizing staff? Could it be a shell script or java program? what kind of programming runtime does an Android device usually have so that I could run a image resizing program? thanks for your reply.

Comment: Java programs are possible, a lot of Android's own tools are Java programs that are started using a small shell script. You just have to make sure the tool does not make use of an Java API not available on Android (see [Android platform API](https://developer.android.com/reference)) Otherwise you can try to use a Linux standard tool compiled for ARMv7/v8a e.g. from Termux repository, but depending on the tool additional libraries may also have to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress the images while you are capturing them, this would have the advantage of keeping the same resolution when you uncompress.

```
$ screencap -p | gzip -c9 > myscreenshot.png.gz
```

Then you can transfer the compressed file and uncompress it to obtain the original image.

Comment: nope, png or jpeg files are already of highly compressed format, the effect is rather trivial when doing more compressions. In this case, I may prefer a quality-losing way.